# Temporarily set a rubocop max metric in my ruby source code?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

I want to do something like:

```
def complex_calculation # rubocop:set Metrics/AbcSize Max=17
  ...
end
```

And temporarily change the maximum allowed `AbcSize` for this method from the default (15) to 17 for this method only.

How would I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rubocop doesn't allow to re-configure metrics within the source code, but it allows to [disable cops within source code](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop#disabling-cops-within-source-code).

You might want to disable the `AbcSize` cops for that method:

```
# rubocop:disable Metrics/AbcSize
def complex_calculation
  # ...
end
# rubocop:enable Metrics/AbcSize
```

You might want to have a look at the [source code of Rubocop's `CommentConfig` class](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/4b26354497f32da8d771f35c66b2f47224f9674b/lib/rubocop/comment_config.rb). Especially the `COMMENT_DIRECTIVE_REGEXP` constant makes it clear that there are no other setting beside `disable` and `enable`...